# How can I programmatically open a new terminal from the current terminal in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am running a bash script inside a vsCode terminal. I want to be able to launch a "docker exec"  shell in another terminal , split vertically.

I know how to create multiple terminals using the vscode keys and menus but was looking for a programmatic way of achieving the same result.

The VS Code terminal cli doesn't seem to have any options - so I'm left wondering if this would be possible.

Answer (score 0):

Since you tagged [vscode-extensions](/questions/tagged/vscode-extensions), can't you do this?:

```js
vscode.commands.executeCommand("workbench.action.terminal.split");
```

There are also the `workbench.action.terminal.splitInActiveWorkspace`, `workbench.action.terminal.splitInstance`, and `workbench.action.terminal.unsplit` commands.

See also: https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-guides/command.